# Positioning objects relative to an ADBannerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad

I've been trying to wrap my head around the coordinates of an iAd banner view, which apparently goes by its own laws. I have a banner view at the bottom of the screen, and I define it likewise:

```
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.scene.view.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = adFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
```

(this is inside of a sprite kit scene) So now, I want to position an object/node relative to this banner view. My first instinct to place this object higher than the banner by 5 was to say

```
node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), adView.frame.size.height + 5);
```

However, this didn't give me any promising results so I decided to hardcode it and it turned out that I was able to get what I wanted if I set the y-value at around 64ish. I tested this value on an iPhone 6, which gave me what I wanted, but then when I tried it on the iPhone 5, it disappeared under the banner view. If the height of the iPhone adBannerView is 50 regardless of the model, this seems to be very contradictory.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It might have something to do with the scene.scaleMode in your GameViewController. Play around with the different settings and see if that helps you.

Comment: my scenes always have scaleMode set to SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill. (Otherwise, there would be a noticeable difference). I've tried to play with the adView as well; I was trying out SizeThatFits: and SizeToFit, but I don't think that did anything. I feel like I'm missing something with the AdBannerView, since I'm able to position everything else just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your scene is being scaled, so the positions you specify will vary across devices. You want to position your nodes relative to the **view** because that is where your banner is located. To do this you can convert the view coordinates to scene coordinates by using the SKView's `convertPointToScene` method. See my answer about positioning nodes relative to the view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171224/2158465) for more info.

You can also choose to not scale your scene at all by setting your scene's `scaleMode` to ResizeFill. This will result in your positions being consistent across devices because there will be no scaling of your coordinates. You can see my answer about scene scaling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256339/2158465) here for more info.