# SKShapeNode is appearing wrong dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I opened spritekit app sample and than added this code

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: view.frame)
    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    shapeNode.lineWidth = 4;
    shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    self.addChild(shapeNode)
}
```

which simply tries to add 4width border in the main view but instead of that output was, 
[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your scene is being scaled. To fix the issue change your scene scale mode (in the GameViewController) to `scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill`

To see why this is, I recommend you read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256339/2158465)