# XCode Scene Editor or Coding for SpriteKit Games

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Is it better to use the Scene Editor inside of XCode for SpriteKit games, or is it better to just programmatically create the game?

Most of the tutorials I have seen for SpriteKit don't even touch the editor, which is why I am asking.

Is it just personal preference? What are the advantages and disadvantages comparatively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is GameScene.sks not recommended for game building?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057345/is-gamescene-sks-not-recommended-for-game-building)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on game to game if you are creating a small game which you want to support ios7 too then best choice programmatically because i think Scene Editor

Scene Editor are always best choice if you targeting ios8 and above these are some major benifits of Scene Editor.

1)easy to set multiple SKScene as you don't need to manually set x and y position of every sprite.

2)live testing of physics simulation don't need to recompile project again and again

3)easy subclassing of sknode instance

4) set physics body propeties easily

5)if ios9 then don't worry about refusing a texture again and again sprite kit handle cache mechainsim for you

6)if ios9 then you have a inbuilt timeline which would help you to create sprite animation live

7)build in custom shader support

8)many more check out below

```
[click here][1]
```

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-604/