# Swift 1.2 SpriteKit coordinate system origin

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates, sprite

I don't know if it is a problem started in Swift 1.2 or not. I am new to both swift and SpriteKit. I was watching an online tutorial and the guy there was able to put a green box on the bottom-left corner of the screen by doing the following:

```
let greenBox = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
let somePoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
greenBox.position = somePoint
self.addChild(greenBox)
```

However when I try the same thing, it does not even appear on the screen! Later, I found out that bottom left of the screen was actually something close to (300,10). Why would that happen?

Also, I found out that the self.frame.size equals to (1024.0, 768.0) which is even more confusing since it has no relation iPhone6's size. (I was testing with iPhone 6 though.)

I am stuck at this. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to set the `scaleMode` of the scene to `.ResizeFill`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with different iOS device resolutions in SpriteKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205882/dealing-with-different-ios-device-resolutions-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things. First of all, make sure your gameViewController.swift has this code in the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
        self.screenSize = skView.frame.size.width

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

This will make sure you have the right aspect ratio and size of an iPhone screen.

To get the bottom left of the screen, you can use this:

```
        let somePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
```

Finally, I believe the greenBox has a center anchor point, so it will put the center of the box in the bottom left which means that about 75% of the block will fall off screen.

You can change the anchor point to the bottom left of the green box to make sure it shows entirely.

```
    greenBox.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

Comment: ViewController does not have screenSize property. And you have assigned that to width which you meant saying "skView.frame.size" I suppose. Rest of your answer helped a lot! Especially the anchorPoint. Feels like I have to read the docs before setting sail.