# SpriteKit View not presenting Scene in ViewController's viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, uivewcontroller

*Goal:*
A red rectangle (of class Brick) should appear in a blue background with node count and fps.

*Reality:*
Gray background and node count and fps (e.g. no red rectangle or blue background)

I have the following code:

**GameViewController**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene: GameScene = GameScene()

        let viewAsSKView = self.view as! SKView
        viewAsSKView.showsFPS = true
        viewAsSKView.showsNodeCount = true
        viewAsSKView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        viewAsSKView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

My best guess it that something's wrong with GameViewController, but I'm not sure what. viewDidLoad() must've been called because I get the fps and node count.

**GameScene**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let myBrick = Brick()
        myBrick.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
        self.addChild(myBrick)

    }

}
```

By the lack of complexity, I assume nothing is wrong with GameScene.

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()       
        self.window!.rootViewController = GameViewController()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

I know that nothing is wrong with my AppDelegate, because if I changed  self.window!.rootViewController to UIViewController, I get my orange screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scene has no size. You can set a size programmatically by initializing the scene using the size initializer.

```
let scene: GameScene = GameScene(size:view.bounds.size)
```

or set your scene's scale mode to `ResizeFill` so that the size of your scene will always resize to match the SKView's size:

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
```

Additionally you may want to view the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256339/2158465) to learn more about Sprite Kit scaling.

Comment: Haha, thanks for coming to the rescue again, @Epic Byte. Unfortunately, though, your solution didn't help me out (although it probably fixed another problem that's not identifiable yet). I still got the same results.

Comment: @SirJony set the background color of your scene, not the SKView.

Comment: @SirJony I'm guessing there is an error displaying your Brick class.

Comment: You're right. So my scene is up and running, but my Brick isn't. I'll take a look at the code, and post a question if I can't solve it. Thanks again! For the viewers of the future, can you update your answer with what you've shown in your comments?