# how does the swift sprite kit SKScene coordinate system work?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

when i add a label to the scene at x=100 y=100, it doesn't show up on the iPhone 6 simulator but when i add it at x=500 it shows up. why doesn't x start from 0?

Comment: May want to see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/25205882/2158465

Comment: Thanks. The information on that post worked, but when i click all the way to the left on the Xcode iPhone 6 simulator, it prints out an x location of about 370. I thought the iPhone 6 had about 700 pixels in the x coordinate so why is the left side only 370 on the simulator?

Comment: `370` is the number of points in coordinate while `750` is the number of pixels in width since the retina (2x) screen.

Comment: ok i think i get it now. thanks